# Real example of Google Analytics profile

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I am going to make a deal with owner of some website, that he will pay me for redirection from my website if it will end with transaction.

ASAIK, he should enable e-commerce tracking in his GA profile, and integrate GA tracking code in his custom made online shop. That is the easy part, which I can handle (I mean, I can explain my client, what he should do).

My client asked me, how to generate proper report, which will be base for our monthly payments. I don't know how to do that, because I never had GA profile with e-commerce data.

I can't wait for first data in my client profile, and then figure out on his profile, because I will not get access to his account (and this is out of the discussion :( ), because in this profile there are a lot sensitive information.

So I thought, maybe there are some fake/example Google Analytics accounts to learn how to use it or create proper report. Do you know any or can you give me some information, how this situation can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

There are no demo accounts in Google Analytics with sample data. The API doesn't have a sandbox. You'll need to populate a profile with sample data of your own by creating a profile and putting the tracking code on a development website.

If your client has a custom made online shop. How certain are you his shop is able to fire off the correct javascript after a purchase is made to register the sale, conversion, and eCommerce data in Google Analytics?

It takes more than just enabling eCommerce tracking in the GA profile settings, I hope you are aware of that.